# Why can't I see folders when using Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I just installed the Google Drive app on my mac to interface my Google drive with the Mac's finder. I see the drive in my Finder and when I navigate to it, I can see all my files.

However, I cannot see any folders -- just files. So for all my content that is stored in a folder, I can't see it. I verified that they all exist by looking t Google Drive using my Browser.

Anyone else find this problem of missing folders?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn’t sure where the proper spot to answer this question was, so I gave this a shot. I’ll move it to SuperUser as you suggested.